# Beamer overlay and listing conundrum

Tags: listings, overlays

When I try to overlay the `lstlisting` C code with escape character (so that I can insert a `\colorbox`), I get the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \let
l.15    }
```

See below for some `beamer` code that reproduces the error. Note that, if I comment out the overlay instructions (see the annotation reading `% comment this` in my code), the code compiles and works perfectly.

I would like the overlay to be operational with my `lstlisting` environment. Any clues as to how to resolve this problem?

```
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}  
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz, subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriftext,stillsansserifsmall]{serif} 
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large,series=\bfseries,shape=\sf}

\definecolor{red}       {rgb}{.8,0,0}
\definecolor{blue}      {rgb}{0,0,.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{C Program}
\only<1>{ % comment this
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}     [language=C,keywordstyle=\color{red},escapechar=\!,basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize]
    !\colorbox{blue}{x++;}!
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,keywordstyle=\color{red},escapechar=\!, basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize]
    !\colorbox{red}{y++;}!
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
} % comment this
\only<2>{ % comment this
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\node at (0,0) {$P_M$};
\node at (1,0) {$P_{W_1}$};
\node at (2,0) {$P_{W_2}$};
\draw (-1,-0.3) -- (3,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
} % Comment this
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some minimal code that reproduces the error(s).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\only<1>{ 
\begin{lstlisting}
\colorbox{blue}{x++;}
\end{lstlisting}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you remove the overlay macro (`\only`), the code compiles fine. This tells you that the problem has nothing to do with `escapechar`. Rather, the problems seems to be that `\only` doesn't appreciate verbatim content (your `lstlisting` environment, in this case).

One workaround is to have your listings in external files and insert them using `\lstinputlisting`; see below.

Side note: `beamer` provides two environments `columns` and `column`, which are more idiomatic than `minipage` is, here. Use them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}  
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz, subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usetheme{boxes}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriftext,stillsansserifsmall]{serif} 
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large,series=\bfseries,shape=\sf}

\definecolor{red}{rgb}{.8,0,0}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,.9}

\begin{filecontents*}{samplex.c}
!\colorbox{blue}{x++;}!
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{sampley.c}
!\colorbox{red}{y++;}!
\end{filecontents*}

\lstdefinestyle{myC}
{
  language=C,
  keywordstyle=\color{red},
  escapechar=!,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{C Program}
\only<1>{
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \lstinputlisting[style=myC]{samplex.c}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \lstinputlisting[style=myC]{sampley.c}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
}
\only<2>{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \node at (0,0) {$P_M$};
    \node at (1,0) {$P_{W_1}$};
    \node at (2,0) {$P_{W_2}$};
    \draw (-1,-0.3) -- (3,-0.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had initially used the columns+column environment, however, I was not sure if that was to blame.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `\only<1>{...}` by `\begin{onlyenv}<1>...\end{onlyenv}` to use verbatim code inside:

```
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz, subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriftext,stillsansserifsmall]{serif}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large,series=\bfseries,shape=\sf}

\definecolor{red}       {rgb}{.8,0,0}
\definecolor{blue}      {rgb}{0,0,.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{C Program}
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}     [language=C,keywordstyle=\color{red},escapechar=\!,basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize]
    !\colorbox{blue}{x++;}!
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,keywordstyle=\color{red},escapechar=\!, basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize]
    !\colorbox{red}{y++;}!
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\node at (0,0) {$P_M$};
\node at (1,0) {$P_{W_1}$};
\node at (2,0) {$P_{W_2}$};
\draw (-1,-0.3) -- (3,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```