# Using listings within a \only section

Tags: beamer, listings, presentations

Is there any way to use listings within `\only` sections of Beamer presentations?

The following is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Boadilla} 
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \frametitle{Brokenframe}

    \begin{columns}[c]
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \only<1>{

                \lstset{language=Haskell} 
                \begin{lstlisting}<1>
                        data SM m = CSR m | COO m | Dense M
                \end{lstlisting}
            }
            \only<2>{           

                \begin{align*}
                    M &= \begin{bmatrix}
                        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 
                        \end{bmatrix}
                \end{align*}
            }
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it however, it gives the following error:

```
./broken.tex:30: Missing } inserted. [  \end{frame}]
./broken.tex:30: LaTeX Error: \begin{lstlisting} on input line 14 ended by \end{beamer@framepauses}. [  \end{frame}]
./broken.tex:30: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [ \end{frame}]
./broken.tex:30: LaTeX Error: \begin{lstlisting} on input line 14 ended by \end{beamer@frameslide}. [   \end{frame}]
./broken.tex:32: LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 6 ended by \end{document}. [   \end{document}]
./broken.tex:32: You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode. [  \end{document}]
./broken.tex:32: LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 6 ended by \end{document}. [   \end{document}]
```

I can fix the above errors by removing the lines `\only<1>{` and `}` around the listings blocks, however that removes the entire point of the block!

Does anyone have any ways of getting around it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176339/32888).

Comment: Ah, perfect! Annoying that I didn't manage to find that in the hour of googling I did before asking. Oh well, my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `\only<1>{...}` by `\begin{onlyenv}<1>...\end{onlyenv}`.

Here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Boadilla}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \frametitle{Brokenframe}

    \begin{columns}[c]
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{onlyenv}<1>

                \lstset{language=Haskell}
\begin{lstlisting}
data SM m = CSR m | COO m | Dense M
\end{lstlisting}
            \end{onlyenv}
            \only<2>{

                \begin{align*}
                    M &= \begin{bmatrix}
                        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
                        \end{bmatrix}
                \end{align*}
            }
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried something similar (using `\begin{only}`) but it looks like I was trying the wrong name.

Thanks! I'm accepting this answer...